# PHP MediaInfo CLI Help

Tags: php

```
<?php
$source_video = 'demo.ts';

$mediaInfoDur_log = 'MEDIAINFO-DURATION-LOG.log';
$mediaInfoDur_cmd_log = 'MEDIAINFO-DURATION-CMD.log';
$mediaInfoDur_cmd = 'mediainfo "--Inform=Video;%Duration%" ' . $source_video;
$mediaInfoDur_cmd = $mediaInfoDur_cmd . ' > ' . $mediaInfoDur_log . ' 2>&1';
$duration = exec($mediaInfoDur_cmd, $output);
print_r($output);
?>
```

How we can send the result of exec into the file and in the array $output ?
The Above method save only in the file nothing shows up in the array
Thanks Sascha

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MediaInfo `--output=xml` parameter to have the output created into an xml file. Set the file path with `--logfile=/path/to/output/output.xml`.

Note that the xml output option is only available on the UNIX version of MediaInfo.